# Limit set of a linear dynamical system

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I would like to find the **limit set** $\omega(x)$ of the linear dynamical system

$$\mathrm f (x_1, x_2) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$$

I tried a few numerical values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ to see the sequence of vectors, but I'm not sure if this is right. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The matrix is positive definite. What can you conclude from that?

Comment: that all points are inside the omega limit set?

Comment: @john  Search   Anosov  diffeomorphisms https://books.google.nl/books?id=3wA3c7-orE8C&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=anosov+diffeomorphism+matrix&source=bl&ots=bH76Q92oF3&sig=tkHJUAHLveNZikil5hVaHjuznc0&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL7M7u9efTAhWSJlAKHZvQBTUQ6AEIdzAI#v=onepage&q=anosov%20diffeomorphism%20matrix&f=false

Comment: thank you, Ali Taghavi, though I learn from examples, and my lecturer gave me this example but I don't understand.